# why does setting an absolute positioned :before content element to an inline element make it overflow its parent?

Tags: html, css

See this codepen:

https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/BMwpjR

HTML

```
<br>
<div class="" style="
">
        <span class="" style="">
Lorem ipsum nunc hendrerit imperdiet aliquet class massa suspendisse libero, enim condimentum himenaeos hendrerit torquent pellentesque per euismod, velit molestie eleifend per rhoncus feugiat fermentum proin.

Suspendisse porttitor diam egestas curabitur malesuada netus enim bibendum, lacinia integer suscipit sem taciti ut nisi nunc, vivamus neque tempor dictum pretium condimentum litora.

Litora primis justo commodo posuere id nullam lacus tempor sociosqu cubilia auctor, nulla maecenas cubilia lacus quisque malesuada risus viverra mattis senectus porttitor ligula a fringilla dui elit nulla hendrerit in condimentum tortor.

Sollicitudin cursus augue semper sodales vitae pel
        </span>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

blockquote, span{
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: salmon;
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    content: '“';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 6px;
    font-size: 4.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 0.75;
    text-align: left;
    color: green;
    font-weight: normal;
}
}
```

Result is overflowing element:

[image]

What do I want? that the salmon red inline element stops overflowing its parent. I want to keep using `:before` and I want to keep it an inline element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `text-indent` instead of padding and make the pseudo element relative to the parent container:

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  text-indent:50px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
span:before {
  content: '“';
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 6px;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 0.75;
  text-align: left;
  color: green;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-indent:0;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div>
  <span>
Lorem ipsum nunc hendrerit imperdiet aliquet class massa suspendisse libero, enim condimentum himenaeos hendrerit torquent pellentesque per euismod, velit molestie eleifend per rhoncus feugiat fermentum proin.

Suspendisse porttitor diam egestas curabitur malesuada netus enim bibendum, lacinia integer suscipit sem taciti ut nisi nunc, vivamus neque tempor dictum pretium condimentum litora.

Litora primis justo commodo posuere id nullam lacus tempor sociosqu cubilia auctor, nulla maecenas cubilia lacus quisque malesuada risus viverra mattis senectus porttitor ligula a fringilla dui elit nulla hendrerit in condimentum tortor.

Sollicitudin cursus augue semper sodales vitae pel
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `padding-left: 50px;` on the `<blockquote>`/`<span>`-tag is causing the issue. If you can use the `::after` pseudo-element, an option would be to create the 50px gab before the text with the `::before` pseudo-element and then position the quotation mark with the `::after` pseudo-element. For example:

```
blockquote,
span {
  background-color: salmon;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  &::after {
    content: "“";
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 6px;
    font-size: 4.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 0.75;
    text-align: left;
    color: green;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}
```

As I'm not sure about all your requirements another way would be using `text-indent` to offset the text.

I'd also advise to specifically set `display: inline;` for your `<blockquote>`/`<span>` selector styling as the default for a `<blockquote>` is `display: block;`.

Comment: You said: "the padding causes this behavior" then I was "no" double checked and you were right. I was "dafuq". So I removed the portion `:before` and left `padding-left:50px` the buggy behavior stayed. But if you make the browser repaint properly, it does not stay. See here: https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/QYOWbM initially no bug, then remove the part that says `REMOVEMEFORSEEINGTHEBUG` this will cause you see the bug. And then undo your change, the bug stays. Will report... btw does not happen in FF, but different odd behaviour bug. I will accept `text-indent` solution below, hope thats ok

Answer (score 0):

If you set the span tag to `display: block;` you should be good.

```
blockquote, span{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-color: salmon;
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

Comment: but that changes the whole way things are displayed... I marked the thing that bothers me with a circle and an arrow, the rest, leave untouched please

Comment: It doesn't change the way its displayed.  the only changes I see are it no longer overflows the container and your padding-left is respected.